# Unable to add validators into EF Produced Metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze

I have a database in Entity Framework that has a set of DTOs created from it that are then consumed by Breeze from the client.

We use the DataAnnotations on the server to validate the data that comes in from Breeze and I want to be able to replicate these validators on the client. Since Breeze implements these validators already and apparently supports adding validators into the metadata I thought I'd give a go  at extending the Breeze Server Project.

I am already aware that EDMXWriter only supports a small set of DataAnnotations.

Basically all my project does is add post-generation the required validators into the json that is sent by Breeze.

**Here is Part of a 'Table' that has the DataAnnotation of StringLength (That Breeze does support) on the Title Property.**

```
{  
    "name":"Table",
    "customannotation:ClrType":"...",
    "key":{  
       "propertyRef":{  
          "name":"Id"
       }
    },
    "property":[  
       {  
          "name":"Title",
          "type":"Edm.String",
          "fixedLength":"false",
          "unicode":"true",
          "validators":[  
             {  
               "validatorName":"stringLength",
               "maxLength":"Max",
               "minLength":1
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

I've formatted the output generation to match the requirements set by the scheme on the breeze website: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema

But Breeze is not interpreting these validators that I am adding to the Metadata.

I noticed that the schema provided by Breeze Server for EF has a different design to the Schema set on the web link above. Does BreezeJS not interpret validators of EF provided Metadata? And if that is the case is there an easy way to enable this or will I have to write that into the client too.

*I was aware that the Breeze team did say that they were planning on implementing better EF DataAnnotation support however I've seen nothing come of that. Perhaps this is implemented already and I've missed something? **One can only hope it will be that easy.***

Regards,
Oliver Baker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two Metadata formats that breeze understands.  The first, which is the default for an EDM (Entity Framework) based model, is a json serialized version of the EDMX CSDL. This is a MS format which cannot easily be extended, and only supports the limited number of data annotations listed above.

The other alternative is breeze's native metadata format.  This format is typically used by any Non Entity Framework based breeze servers. This is also the format used when applying the *MetadataStore.exportMetadata* and *MetadataStore.importMetadata* method calls. If your server provides metadata in this format then you can include whatever validations you want. The best way to investigate this format is to simply export the metadata for your current application and take a look.  The result is simply the stringified native metadata json.

One approach that several breeze developers have taken is use a prebuild process that  roundtrips the CSDL formatted metadata from an EF server thru a breeze client to translate it into native format and then simply storing this result on the server ( in your case with some added validators) and simply returning this prestored metadata to the client in production during the Metadata call.

In addition, you can also extend the breeze metadata format: See:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-metadata

We have a number of developers who use such extended metadata for a variety of purposes, including the addition of validation metadata.

Comment: Server side EDMX CSDL to native json metadata would simplify the whole story (EFDatacontextProvider). Drop CSDL metadata support on the client.

Comment: @Jay Will there be any plans by Breeze to extend the Validation provided by the EFDatacontext in the near/mid-term future?

Comment: It's on our list, but it may take awhile.  We do offer professional support contracts ( contact breeze@ideablade.com) that can expedite requests like this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the EFContextProvider has very limited validation annotation support, basically just:

- required - if !isNullable
- maxLength - if maxLength is specified

The output listed at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema is of the metadata object in the client library, once processed.

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation shows how to manually edit this information, and notes the following:

> Many of these validators correlate to .NET data annotations . In a future release, the Breeze.NET EFContextProviderwill be able to include these validations in the metadata automatically for you. For now, you'll have to add them to the properties on the client side as we show next.

So if you extend the EFContextProvider with additional metadata, you'll have to manually process this and add it to the validators objects in the property info in the metadata store.

Answer (score 0):

> One approach that several breeze developers have taken is use a prebuild process that roundtrips the CSDL formatted metadata from an EF server thru a breeze client to translate it into native format and then simply storing this result on the server

Here is my solution using jint, up on [github](https://github.com/mcshaz/SimManager/blob/master/SM.DTOs/MedSimDtoMetadata.cs). Obviously computationally expensive, so the method calling this has a [Conditional["DEBUG"]] attribute

```
public static class MedSimDtoMetadata
{
    const string breezeJsPath = @"C:\Users\OEM\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SimManager\SM.Web\Scripts\breeze.min.js";
    public static string GetBreezeMetadata(bool pretty = false)
    {
        var engine = new Engine().Execute("var setInterval;var setTimeout = setInterval = function(){}"); //if using an engine like V8.NET, would not be required - not part of DOM spec

        engine.Execute(File.ReadAllText(breezeJsPath));
        engine.Execute("breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();" + //mirror here what you are doing in the client side code
                       "var edmxMetadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();" +
                       "edmxMetadataStore.importMetadata(" + MedSimDtoRepository.GetEdmxMetadata() + ");" +
                       "edmxMetadataStore.exportMetadata();");
        var exportedMeta = JObject.Parse(engine.GetCompletionValue().AsString());
        AddValidators(exportedMeta);
        return exportedMeta.ToString(pretty ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None);
    }


    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570638/how-to-add-extend-breeze-entity-types-with-metadata-pulled-from-property-attribu
    static void AddValidators(JObject metadata)
    {
        Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(ParticipantDto).Assembly; //any type in the assembly containing the Breeze entities.
        var attrValDict = GetValDictionary();
        var unaccountedVals = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var breezeEntityType in metadata["structuralTypes"])
        {
            string shortEntityName = breezeEntityType["shortName"].ToString();
            string typeName = breezeEntityType["namespace"].ToString() + '.' + shortEntityName;
            Type entityType = thisAssembly.GetType(typeName, true);
            Type metaTypeFromAttr = ((MetadataTypeAttribute)entityType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), false).Single()).MetadataClassType;

            foreach (var breezePropertyInfo in breezeEntityType["dataProperties"])
            {
                string propName = breezePropertyInfo["name"].ToString();
                propName = char.ToUpper(propName[0]) + propName.Substring(1); //IF client using breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase & server using PascalCase
                var propInfo = metaTypeFromAttr.GetProperty(propName);

                if (propInfo == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No metadata property attributes available for " + breezePropertyInfo["dataType"] + " "+ shortEntityName +'.' + propName);
                    continue;
                }

                var validators = breezePropertyInfo["validators"].Select(bp => bp.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()).ToDictionary(key => (string)key["name"]);

                //usingMetaProps purely on property name - could also use the DTO object itself
                //if metadataType not found, or in reality search the entity framework entity
                //for properties with the same name (that is certainly how I am mapping)


                foreach (Attribute attr in propInfo.GetCustomAttributes())
                {
                    Type t = attr.GetType();
                    if (t.Namespace == "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Func<Attribute, Dictionary<string,object>> getVal;
                    if (attrValDict.TryGetValue(t, out getVal))
                    {
                        var validatorsFromAttr = getVal(attr);
                        if (validatorsFromAttr != null)
                        {
                            string jsValidatorName = (string)validatorsFromAttr["name"];
                            if (jsValidatorName == "stringLength")
                            {
                                validators.Remove("maxLength");
                            }
                            Dictionary<string, object> existingVals;
                            if (validators.TryGetValue(jsValidatorName, out existingVals))
                            {
                                existingVals.AddOrOverwrite(validatorsFromAttr);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                validators.Add(jsValidatorName, validatorsFromAttr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unaccountedVals.Add(t.FullName);
                    }

                }

                breezePropertyInfo["validators"] = JToken.FromObject(validators.Values);
            }
        }
        foreach (var u in unaccountedVals)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("unaccounted attribute:" + u);
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<Type, Func<Attribute, Dictionary<string, object>>> GetValDictionary()
    {
        var ignore = new Func<Attribute, Dictionary<string, object>>(x => null);
        return new Dictionary<Type, Func<Attribute, Dictionary<string, object>>>
        {
            [typeof(RequiredAttribute)] = x => new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "required",
                ["allowEmptyStrings"] = ((RequiredAttribute)x).AllowEmptyStrings
                //["message"] = ((RequiredAttribute)x).ErrorMessage
            },
            [typeof(EmailAddressAttribute)] = x => new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "emailAddress",
            },
            [typeof(PhoneAttribute)] = x => new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "phone",
            },
            [typeof(RegularExpressionAttribute)] = x => new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "regularExpression",
                ["expression"] = ((RegularExpressionAttribute)x).Pattern
            },
            [typeof(StringLengthAttribute)] = x => {
                var sl = (StringLengthAttribute)x;
                return GetStrLenDictionary(sl.MaximumLength, sl.MinimumLength);
            },
            [typeof(MaxLengthAttribute)] = x => GetStrLenDictionary(((MaxLengthAttribute)x).Length),
            [typeof(UrlAttribute)] = x => new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "url",
            },
            [typeof(CreditCardAttribute)] = x=> new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "creditCard",
            },
            [typeof(FixedLengthAttribute)] = x => //note this is one of my attributes to force fixed length
            {
                var len = ((FixedLengthAttribute)x).Length;
                return GetStrLenDictionary(len, len);
            },
            [typeof(RangeAttribute)] = x => {
                var ra = (RangeAttribute)x;
                return new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["name"] = "range",
                    ["min"] = ra.Minimum,
                    ["max"] = ra.Maximum
                }; 
            },
            [typeof(KeyAttribute)] = ignore
        };
    }

    static Dictionary<string,object> GetStrLenDictionary(int maxLength, int minLength = 0)
    {
        if (minLength == 0)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["name"] = "maxLength",
                ["maxLength"] = maxLength
            };
        }
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["name"] = "stringLength",
            ["minLength"] = minLength,
            ["maxLength"] = maxLength
        };
    }

    static void AddOrOverwrite<K,V>(this Dictionary<K,V> oldValues, Dictionary<K,V> newValues)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<K,V> kv in newValues)
        {
            if (oldValues.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
            {
                oldValues[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                oldValues.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this code only works with the pending fix for JInt [Date.prototype.toISOString pre 1970](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/issues/285)

Comment: Hey, I should let you know that I wrote a custom implementation that extended the existing metadata exporter that correctly added validators in and then wrote a precompiler for the breezejs library to correctly interpret the validators. Thanks very much for the response though, I might use it if I use breezejs again. (No longer working with the company I needed this solution for, breezejs is still great)