# how to add extend breeze entity types with metadata pulled from property attributes

Tags: entity-framework, attributes, breeze

I want to get the custom attributes, mentioned below, in breeze dataService (client side).

```
namespace Tam.Framework.Web.Models
{
    [ViewAttribute("app/views/Employee.html")]//this custom class attribute
    public class Employee : BaseEntity
    {
        protected override string OnGetDescriptor()
        {
            return "some description";
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "LAST NAME")]//this custom property attribute
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var manager = configureBreezeManager();

        function configureBreezeManager() {

        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('api/breeze');
        model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
        mgr.fetchMetadata(function (metadata) {
            return initializeMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore, metadata);
        });
        return mgr;
    };




       function initializeMetadataStore(metadataStore, metadata) {
        breeze.NamingConvention.defaultInstance = breeze.NamingConvention.none;
        var metadataType, metadataProperty, entityProperty, i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < metadata.schema.entityType.length; i++) {
            metadataType = metadata.schema.entityType[i];
            var entityType = metadataStore.getEntityType(metadataType.name);
            for (j = 0; j < metadataType.property.length; j++) {
                metadataProperty = metadataType.property[j];

                    entityProperty = entityType.getProperty(metadataProperty.name);

                if (entityProperty) {
                    if (typeof metadataProperty.displayName !== 'undefined') {
                        entityProperty.displayName = metadataProperty.displayName;
                    }
                    if (typeof metadataProperty.displayOrder !== 'undefined') {
                        entityProperty.displayOrder = metadataProperty.displayOrder;
                    }
                    if (typeof metadataProperty.autoGenerateField !== 'undefined') {
                        entityProperty.autoGenerateField = metadataProperty.autoGenerateField;
                    }
                    if (typeof metadataProperty.allowEmptyStrings !== 'undefined') {
                        entityProperty.allowEmptyStrings = metadataProperty.allowEmptyStrings;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }





        var readData = function (entityName, observableResults, showLog) {

        if (!entityName || !observableResults)
            return null;

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from(entityName);


        return manager.executeQuery(query)
         .then(querySucceeded)
         .fail(queryFailed);
    }

    function readEmployee() {
    return breezeDataService.readData("Employees", employees, true).then(function () {

        var propertyDisplayName = employees()[0].entityType.getProperty('lastName').displayName;//error displayName undefined
     }
    }
```

when I get list of entity by readData function that list (observableResults[0]) have not any displayName but I add displayName and checked it by initializeMetadataStore function is correct

FINALLY!!!!! I found it it because of breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();

Answer (score 5):

On the server, add logic to the Metadata controller action to supplement the standard metadata with the display attribute properties:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual string Metadata()
{
    // Extend metadata with extra attributes
    var metadata = JObject.Parse(this.ContextProvider.Metadata());
    var ns = metadata["schema"]["namespace"].ToString();
    foreach (var breezeEntityType in metadata["schema"]["entityType"])
    {
        var typeName = ns + "." + breezeEntityType["name"].ToString();
        var entityType = BuildManager.GetType(typeName, true);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            var attributes = propertyInfo.GetAllAttributes();
            var breezePropertyInfo = breezeEntityType["property"].SingleOrDefault(p => p["name"].ToString() == propertyInfo.Name);
            if (breezePropertyInfo == null)
                continue;

            // handle display attribute...
            var displayAttribute = attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (displayAttribute != null)
            {
                var displayName = displayAttribute.GetName();
                if (displayName != null)
                    breezePropertyInfo["displayName"] = displayName;
                var displayOrder = displayAttribute.GetOrder();
                if (displayOrder != null)
                    breezePropertyInfo["displayOrder"] = displayOrder;
                var autogenerateField = displayAttribute.GetAutoGenerateField();
                if (autogenerateField != null)
                    breezePropertyInfo["autoGenerateField"] = autogenerateField;
            }

            // allowEmptyStrings.
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                breezePropertyInfo["allowEmptyStrings"] = true;
                var requiredAttribute = attributes.OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (requiredAttribute != null && !requiredAttribute.AllowEmptyStrings)
                    breezePropertyInfo["allowEmptyStrings"] = false;
            }

            // todo: handle other types of attributes...
        }
    }

    return metadata.ToString();
}
```

On the client, fetch the metadata and supplement the breeze entity type with the custom metadata.

```
function initializeMetadataStore(metadataStore, metadata) {
    var metadataType, metadataProperty, entityProperty, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < metadata.schema.entityType.length; i++) {
        metadataType = metadata.schema.entityType[i];
        var entityType = metadataStore.getEntityType(metadataType.name);
        for (j = 0; j < metadataType.property.length; j++) {
            metadataProperty = metadataType.property[j];
            entityProperty = entityType.getProperty(metadataProperty.name);
            if (entityProperty) {
                if (typeof metadataProperty.displayName !== 'undefined') {
                    entityProperty.displayName = metadataProperty.displayName;
                }
                if (typeof metadataProperty.displayOrder !== 'undefined') {
                    entityProperty.displayOrder = metadataProperty.displayOrder;
                }
                if (typeof metadataProperty.autoGenerateField !== 'undefined') {
                    entityProperty.autoGenerateField = metadataProperty.autoGenerateField;
                }
                if (typeof metadataProperty.allowEmptyStrings !== 'undefined') {
                    entityProperty.allowEmptyStrings = metadataProperty.allowEmptyStrings;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var entityManager = ....something...;
entityManager.fetchMetadata(function (metadata) {
    return initializeMetadataStore(entityManager.metadataStore, metadata);
});
```

now the additional metadata is available in the breeze entity type...

```
var propertyDisplayName = myEntity.entityType.getProperty('lastName').displayName;
```

Comment: thanks Jeremy I used that function and add custom attribute but I have error in last step   myEntity.entityType.getProperty('lastName').displayName;// displayName undefined

Comment: to confirm this is setup properly in your solution set a breakpoint in the server code on this line: `breezePropertyInfo["displayName"] = displayName;`.   Then set another breakpoint in the client-side code on this line: `entityProperty.displayName = metadataProperty.displayName;`.  You should be hitting both breakpoints.  When the breakpoints are hit, confirm the `propertyInfo` / `entityProperty` variables contain the property you expect.

Comment: I checked both assignments and was correct but I think have problem to update metadata can you check this. I don't know this config is correct or not....                                          function configureBreezeManager() {
            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('api/breeze');
            mgr.fetchMetadata(function (metadata) {
                return initializeMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore, metadata);
            });
            model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
            return mgr;
        };